# How can you write almost type safe code having a list of objects within a class?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-safety

I am looking for a way to write almost type safe / maintainable code in Python while using a list of objects.
I have found the following way of enforcing intellisense functionality (tested in vscode):

```
class MyObject(object):
    key1 = None
    key2 = None

a = MyObject()

v = []


def add_element():
    a = MyObject()
    a.key1 = 1
    v.append(a)

add_element()

# this works (intellisense)
print(v[0].key1)
```

However, when used inside a class, the same idea does not work anymore (with regards to intellisense):

```
class MyClass():
    v = []

    def add_element(self):
        a = MyObject()
        a.key1 = 1
        self.v.append(a)

    def use_element(self):
        # this does not show (intellisense)
        print(self.v[0].key1)


c = MyClass()

c.add_element()
c.use_element()
```

I'm guessing there should be a simple fix for this.

Comment: You've defined `v` to be a class level variable and is shared with all instances of this class.

Comment: You're right. So that's why it was not working actually! I was doing this so I could use the variable like this `MyClass.v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to make `v` an instance attribute:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.v = []

    def add_element(self):
        a = MyObject()
        a.key1 = 1
        self.v.append(a)

    def use_element(self):
        # this does not show (intellisense)
        print(self.v[0].key1)
```

But you said type-safe, which means you should also add type annotations and run mypy on your code to make sure all the code is using your expected types appropriately.

```py
from typing import List

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.v: List[MyObject] = []

    def add_element(self) -> None:
        a = MyObject()
        a.key1 = 1
        self.v.append(a)

    def use_element(self) -> None:
        # this does not show (intellisense)
        print(self.v[0].key1)
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for type safety in a more loose term (just class attribute definitions), but this is useful addition